# Handling different delimiters in a csv file in java

Tags: java, csv

I am using `csvRecordsReader.importDataFromCsv()` method to read my csv files. Now, as an argument, i need to give the csv file and the delimiter used in the csv file. But what if i don't know the delimiter beforehand? what if the delimiter is a semicolon instead of comma? Is there a way to find out the delimiter used in a csv file automatically?

Comment: No. The fields may contain characters that you might incorrectly presume to be delimiters.

Comment: makes sense. then how do i find out whether a comma or a semicolon was used as a delimiter without manually opening and checking it?

Comment: Do you have any control over the source of these CSV files? If so, mandate that they all use the same delimiter. Or if this is some tool or API to read a CSV file, and you have no control over the CSV files, then add a parameter to allow users to specify the delimiter used, with comma (`,`) being the sensible default.

Comment: Can you provide me with an example? a row or two from your CSV file.

Comment: @ashishraaj it is just a simple csv file. but sometimes the user wants to upload the file using semicolon as the delimiter and sometimes using comma. but the file does not contain both of the delimiters. it is just the users' preference.

Comment: The update probably happens with a form? In that case add a input control where the user selects if they are using commas or semicolons. However "commas or semicolons" isn't the only option when creating CSV files. What about quoting and escaping (just to name two of DOZENS of them)? Are you letting the user choose those as well? I think you are trying to solve the wrong problem. Why CSV in first place? Why not a fixed format? Where does the data come from?

Answer (score 1):

Either you

- create code that reads the first few lines, evaluates and decides on the delimiter automatically (similar to what @ashishraaj suggested)
- let the user provide the separator character togeher with the file
- limit your code to support only one

I do not think there are alternatives.

For finding the separator character automatically, the first line could be a good hint. It contains column names and separator characters. You'd need to identify what are reasonable column names and could then spot the separator characters.

If you only have to decide between comma and semicolon, the chances of getting it right are even higher. Just try to read the CSV with e.g. comma, check if you get a reasonable amount of columns. Then do the same for semicolon.